# React navigation Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(AuthScreen)"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation, expo

I'm trying to facebook login with my expo react native app. But i have a problem. I used redux. My **app.js** here.

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator,  createAppContainer, createStackNavigator 

} from 'react-navigation';

import AuthScreen from './screens/AuthScreen';
import { Provider } from  'react-redux'
import store from './store';

const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  welcome: {screen: WelcomeScreen},
  auth: { screen: AuthScreen },
  main: {
    screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
      map: { screen: MapScreen },
      deck: { screen: DeckScreen },
      review: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
          review: { screen: ReviewScreen },
          settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
        })
      }
    })
  }
})

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store} >
        <View>
          <MainNavigator/>
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}


export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator)
```

And this is my **AuthScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/auth_actions';

class AuthScreen extends Component {
    componentDidMoun(){
        this.props.facebookLogin();
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Auth</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(AuthScreen);
```

I called **facebookLogin()** function inside my **auth_action.js** file

```
export const facebookLogin = () => async dispatch => {

let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fb_token');
  if(token) {
    dispatch({ type: FACEBOOK_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: token })
  }else{
      doFacebookLogin(dispatch);
  }
}
```

reducer/**index.js** file

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export default combineReducers({
    auth: () => { return {} }
});
```

And this is my **store.js** file.

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from '../reducers';

const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    {},
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
);

export default store;
```

But i'm getting this error.

**Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(AuthScreen)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(AuthScreen) in connect options.**

What is a problem? Can you help me?

Comment: How did you solve this? Please answer. I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have not connected your store to this component `export default connect(null, actions)(AuthScreen);` and you have passed `null` where you should pass some `mapper` and just `action` where you should define which functions you want to import from reducer.

Comment: I changed like this. `const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        facebookLogin: () => dispatch(facebookLogin())
    }
}` But it's not working

Comment: Same error. :( Could not find "store" in the context

Comment: so same answer you need to `mapStateToProps` up to now you have mapped needed function from `auth_action` but what about the state? 
Also, I am not sure about the usage of compose in createStore

Comment: https://github.com/ipeedy/react-native-boilerplate  
Can be helpful, look at the `screens/setting` for example

Comment: Thank you so much your answer. I will try boilerplate and mapStateToProps.

Comment: @EbruGulec How did you soled this, Please tell me. I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions";
import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator
} from "react-navigation";

import AuthScreen from "../screens/AuthScreen";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import SettingsScreen from "../screens/SettingsScreen";
import DeckScreen from "../screens/DeckScreen";
import MapScreen from "../screens/MapScreen";
import ReviewScreen from "../screens/ReviewScreen";

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  auth: { screen: AuthScreen },
  main: {
    screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
      map: { screen: MapScreen },
      deck: { screen: DeckScreen },
      review: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
          review: { screen: ReviewScreen },
          settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
        })
      }
    })
  }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

    enter code here

class AppNavigation extends Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer screenProps={this.props} />;
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  actions
)(AppNavigation);
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import AppNavigation from "./navigation/AppNavigation";
import store from "./store";
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppNavigation />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```